# How to give a div element a percentage height in tinyscrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tinyscrollbar

I'm using a simple jquery plugin `tinyscrollbar` to create a custom scrollbar for a div element.

everything works fine.

But my div has a height in percentage `%`.

But the tinyscrollbar is forcing me to use `pixels` for the height of the div which is not what I want.

I tried to change the height like this without any success:

```
#scrollbar1 .viewport { width: 80%; height: 80%;}
```

But this works fine:

```
#scrollbar1 .viewport { width: 80%; height: 200px;}
```

This is a working FIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/4a1v0xso/

Can someone please advice on this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With `top:0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; position: absolute;` on `#scrollbar1`, it's working with a percentage on the `height` of the `viewport`. But, I'm not sure you want to have an absolute position.

Comment: If your scrollbar is under main 'body' tag then you can set '80vh' instead of '80%'. It will take also 80% from screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the css like this. Just add `position:absoute;` it works for me.

```
#scrollbar1 .viewport { width: 80%; height: 90%; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; }
```